# Referencing a table to look up values between worksheets in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Ok so here's a doosy of a question:

I work in healthcare, currently I have a workbook that references values using an INDEX:MATCH function based off of a patients name, which I manually enter.  I pull 7/10 columns using this method automatically.  The 8th column is the generation date of the information and the 9th column is a date/time stamp from another sheet which I enter manually based off of the patient's room number.

Here's the tricky part.  The two reports, which I'm pulling from our bed management program Allscripts, don't translate the bed names/numbers the same way.  So I created a translation table in a different sheet.  My question is this:  Is there a way I can use a function like INDEX:MATCH, VLOOKUP or something else within either Excel or VBA to reference my translation table in order to look up the bed name/number and auto fill the information I need?

Spreadsheet looks like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j8b2jZ7ZUzKpmoqoisFBVccDKw_CWDfWCGL_CcO2hCo/edit?usp=sharing

So Column G on the 'Raw Data Page' needs to reference column E from the same page, translate that bed name based off of the 'Bed Translation Page' and then look up the date/time information from the 'Job Activity Detail' page in Column G for that translated bed.  The catch is the bed names are repeated over 100k times in my current workbook due to the day by day entry of data (I manually change the search range in the INDEX:MATCH function for each column).

I hope someone can shed some light on this for me, it's been the bane of my existence for nearly two years now!  Appreciate any info/help any of you may be able to provide!  :)

Comment: I think your best bet is doing an if then statement assessing whether column E in the Raw package sheet, is equal to the translation data, and if so select this cell and then use .offset(0,1). then save that as a variable and use application.match to retrieve that value from the other sheet. Once you have retrieved that value, use offset to retrieve the value that you ultimately want to have. You can also use .find to match the row between column E and translationsheet then use .find again to retrieve the column from the other sheet, then ultimately find the value you want.

Comment: I actually may have stumbled upon the answer.... If I use this function: =VLOOKUP(INDEX('Portal of Entry Detail'!$O$32479:$O$32535,MATCH('Raw Data Page'!C15455,'Portal of Entry Detail'!$B$32479:$B$32535,0)),'Bed Translation'!A:B,2,FALSE) to look up the bed name and then this function: =INDEX('Job Activity Detail'!$G$106463:$G$106689,MATCH('Raw Data Page'!E15455,'Job Activity Detail'!$A$106463:$A$106689,0))  to look up the date/time stamp I need it works.  The only problem I have is repeat bed name values on the 'Job Activity Detail' sheet

Comment: Hmm, that is great news, although tricky with a lack of unique identifiers, is there another variable you can pull? If you have multiple entries it defeats the whole purpose of the exercise.Could you concatenate any similar information into the translation sheet?

Comment: The way I do it now is by cross-referencing the Bed Available time.  It's the only identifier that's the same in both reports.  I'm thinking an IF statement but I don't know exactly how to write it...

Comment: If you use replace to remove the - from the identifier and then use .find in vba you can easily find the other value and forget the whole translation table. As for the if statement, if you knew something like the date or something you could use AND in an if statement, and check another column on the same row as the matched identifier.

Comment: Ok so my VBA skills may be... inadequate for this to work.  And by inadequate i mean I don't know the language! :*(  I see what you're saying but I wouldn't know how to write the script.  On the two sheets the values that are the same would be the Bed Available Time (column J on the Portal of Entry Detail) and the Final Status Date & Time (column M on the Job Activity Detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great news man, you will not need this so! It pulls in column G from the job activity detail, where the identifier on rawdata page is equal to the identifier on job activity detail and the name is the same on Job Activity Detail and Portal of Entry Detail and the two times in J and M of the respective sheets match.

```
Option Explicit

Sub bd()

Dim rdsheet As Worksheet, jbsheet As Worksheet, btsheet As Worksheet
Dim bdstr, bdendrow, rng As Range, y, Key, GCell, BdCell

Set rdsheet = Sheets("Raw Data Page")
Set jbsheet = Sheets("Job Activity Detail")
Set btsheet = Sheets("Portal of Entry Detail")

bdstr = rdsheet.Range("G3").Address
bdendrow = rdsheet.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
Set rng = rdsheet.Range(bdstr & ":G" & bdendrow)

For Each y In rng
If IsEmpty(y) Then

Key = y.Offset(0, -2).Value
Key = Replace(Key, "-", "")

Set GCell = jbsheet.Range("A:A").Find(what:=Key, LookAt:=xlPart)
Set BdCell = btsheet.Range("B:B").Find(what:=y.Offset(0, -4).Value, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Not GCell Is Nothing And btsheet.Range("J" & BdCell.Row).Value = jbsheet.Range("M" & GCell.Row).Value Then
rdsheet.Range(y.Address) = jbsheet.Range("G" & GCell.Row)

End If
End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm going to apply it and see how it does.  Appreciate all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

{=INDEX('Job Activity Detail'!$G$106463:$G$106689,MATCH('Raw Data Page'!E15459&H15459,'Job Activity Detail'!$A$106463:$A$106689&'Job Activity Detail'!$M$106463:$M$106689,0))}  looking up the value as an array function with multiple match criteria seems to be working!  I appreciate the insight Lowpar! :)